# EFM8 BB51 internal temperature sensor and gain

Tags: microcontroller, adc, gain, siliconlabs

I am setting up ADC0 on the EFM8 BB51 to read the internal temperature sensor. I am having a hard time understanding how the gain settings impact the values of the temp sensor.

```
mov CLKGRP0, #18h     ; Enable SAR clock, at 12MHz
mov ADC0CF1, #0Ah     ; 800ns tracking time
mov ADC0CF2, #2Fh     ; 1.65V reference
mov ADC0CN0, #85h     ; ADC enabled (gain 0.5, temp sensor enabled)
mov ADC0CN1, #20h     ; 10bit mode
mov ADC0MX,  #10h     ; Select temp sensor input

mov ADC0CN0, #95h     ; initialize conversion
```

The BB51 does not provide an internal reference voltage of 3.3 V (only ranges for using VDD as a reference voltage if powered by a stable power supply), that's why I went with a 0.5 gain and 1.65V reference instead.

When reading `ADC0H` and `ADC0L` I get double the temperature I expect. I'm not sure if I should just right shift once and be done with it, or if there actually is an offset I need to take into account, e.g. accounting for negative temperature readings.

Neither in the [datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm8bb51-datasheet.pdf) nor in the [reference manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efm8bb51-rm.pdf) I can find any pointers on how to actually implement the readings from the internal temperature sensor.

How do I properly interpret the temperature readings on the EFM8 BB51? What is the range it is able to measure? Is a reading of `0x0000` for both the H and the L byte equivalent to 0°C?

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments by user @V.V.T the problem was the voltage offset at 0ºC. So my issued was not related to the gain settings (which in fact are working as expected), but rather to not accounting for the voltage offset.

Digging deeper in the codebase made me realize that temperature readings were handled, accounting for offsets used by the BB2 and in this specific use case the methods applied would not properly work.

Reading double the value in the low byte, lead me to wrong conclusions here.

Comment: By “twice the temperature” do you mean ~600K? Or ~20 error in degrees C? The offset of the on-chip temperature sensor is not guaranteed at all, hence the section on single point calibration. What about the slope?I have never found these on-chip MCU temperature sensors particularly useful due to poor tolerances and exposure to die temperature fluctuations.

Comment: read again datasheet page 30, Table 4.15. Temperature Sensor, Offset voltage \$V_{OFF.TSENSE}\$ @ 0ºC typical 883 mV. That is, when at the water freezing temperature, the sensor output voltage is about 0.883V plus/minus Offset error of 0.020V. Nominal slope \$M_{TSENSE}\$ is 2.95 mV/ºC

Comment: @V.V.T - thank you. Not sure how I missed this.

Comment: Did you enable the temperature sensor?

Comment: Did you read the section 13.3.10 Temperature Sensor?